# Function that must have a generic interface, but must behaves differently based on passed subclasses (without knowing what they are!) - C++

Tags: c++, dynamic, polymorphism, overloading, dynamic-cast

I'm writing C++.

I have different classes inheriting from a base class (say, A, B, C, D all inheriting from Z).

I want to write a function that takes 2 objects of type (super-type) Z and performs some operation. (For example, I could have `f(a, b)` or `f(c,d)`, where a, b, c, d are of types A, B, C, D respectively).

I want the interface (of the function) to be general (no `f_AB(a,b)` and `f_CD(c,d)`).

However, the implementations can (and do) differ based on the classes that are taken in. (E.g. I do have `f_AB` that does something A-B specific, `f_CD` that does something C-D specific, as well as `f_AC`, `f_BC`, etc.)

The subclasses have totally different data and the specific operations are completely different based on the classes that I compare.

When I am using this function I do not know the specific subclasses of the 2 arguments. Assume that I am doing something like

```
for p in Z {
  for q in Z
    f(p, q) # p and q could be of any subclass of Z! and f must behave accordingly!
}
```

What is the best way of solving this problem in C++? I am not able to combine polymorphism, virtual methods, overloading and dynamic casts to fully solve the problem.

In case this is not solvable, is it possible to solve it by giving up some assumptions? (Like using inheritance, which is really just needed for having generic references to loop over my objects)

Comment: In the nested loop example I provided, I could to `f(dynamic_cast<P>(p), dynamic_cast<Q>(q))` only if I knew what are the subclasses `P` and `Q` of `p` and `q` ! But as I said, I don't know them. Maybe there is a way of finding out of what specific type an object is? Or maybe I should keep an internal label/id in the objects that maps to my subclasses. Like a `unsigned type` member, with an external map that maps 0 to A, 1 to B, etc. What do you think?

Comment: This problem is called double (or multiple) dispatch. Usually solved by a function pointer 2D table, or by the visitor pattern.

Comment: Interesting! I'll read about multiple dispatch and the visitor pattern. Basically the 2D function pointer table is like an external vtable, right? (And the vtable could be seen as a 1D function pointer table (1D array) since it only presents alternatives for a single argument (implicit in this case: `this` or `self`))

Comment: Exactly._______

Answer (score 0):

This should do:

```
class A;

class B;

class C;

class D;

class ZVisitor;


class Z
{
public:
    virtual void Accept (ZVisitor *zv) = 0;

    virtual void f(A* a) = 0;

    virtual void f(B* b) = 0;

    virtual void f(C* c) = 0;

    virtual void f(D* c) = 0;
};

class A : public Z
{
public:

    void Accept(ZVisitor *zv)
    {
        zv->Handle(this);
    }

    void f(A* a);

    void f(B* b);

    void f(C* c);

    void f(D* c);
};

class B : public Z
{
public:
    void Accept(ZVisitor *zv)
    {
        zv->Handle(this);
    }

    void f(A* a);

    void f(B* b);

    void f(C* c);

    void f(D* c);
};

class C : public Z
{
public:

    void Accept(ZVisitor *zv)
    {
        zv->Handle(this);
    }


    void f(A* a);

    void f(B* b);

    void f(C* c);

    void f(D* c);
};

class D : public Z
{
public:
    void Accept(ZVisitor *zv)
    {
        zv->Handle(this);
    }

    void f(A* a);

    void f(B* b);

    void f(C* c);

    void f(D* c);
};

class ZVisitor
{
private:
    Z *z;

public:

    ZVisitor(Z *z)
    {
        this->z = z;
    }

    void Handle(A* a)
    {
        z->f(a);
    }

    void Handle(B* b)
    {
        z->f(b);
    }

    void Handle(C* c)
    {
        z->f(c);
    }

    void Handle(D* d)
    {
        z->f(d);
    }

};

void f(Z *z1, Z *z2)
{
    ZVisitor zvisitor(z2);

    z1->Accept(&zvisitor);
}
```